# Automatic Language changed in Android App

Tags: android, android-studio, local-storage

I have one Android app which contain two languages. if I am not use app for some time language is automatically changed to English.

Comment: Your app will follow the system language, you are probably changing your system language.

Comment: Is there any solution on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]    You need to set the selected language code in preference and set the locale on splash screen.
    public static String ENGLISH = "en";
    setLang("en");
        String lang = getLang(this);

```
    public void setLang(Context context, String value)

    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("setLang", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("getLang", value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getLang(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("setLang", 0);
        String value = prefs.getString("getLang", null);

        return value;

    }

public void setLocale(String lang) {

        myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

    }
```

Comment: u also need to add different value folders in res folder according to language.. and use language codes

Comment: yes i created two different folder for two languages. It works fine  if i use app without hold if i don't use app for 5-10 min then language is changed.

Comment: like the attached image you need to provide different values with same key but different values according to the language

Comment: I know that i have created the same.

Comment: you can do one more thing create a base class and  call setLocale method in onResume() Fuction and extend this base class in every activity you use in your aplication

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92966/discussion-between-rohit-heera-and-yogi).

Answer (score 0):

In android applications language is set the same as system language. Default application language is set if system language is not supported by app.

Comment: Its changed to my local langauge  but if i don't use app for some time then language changes to English.

Answer (score 0):

Android offers the possibility to localize your string for using different language. You should read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html